# what does Ctrl + w + Tab do in vim

Tags: vim

I opened up two windows in vim and was trying to switch between windows, but accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl+w+Tab</kbd> (instead of <kbd>Ctrl + w + h</kbd>). If the cursor is currently on `#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>`, vim would open a new horizontal new window and open the file /usr/include/boost/multi_array/extent_range.hpp, and leave the cursor on the line `namespace multi_array{`.

If I am in `.bashrrc` file and do the same thing on a `export`, it would open another window and open `.bashrc` again, with the cursor located in the place where `export` first appears.

I tried to search for what the use is for this shortcut, but cannot find any. I also checked my `.vimrc` but don't see any key mappings for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing that you need to know is that in a terminal, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> are indistinguishable (both are ASCII character 9).

So we check the docs (`:help CTRL-W`) and see

> CTRL-W CTRL-I     same as "CTRL-W i"

and looking under "CTRL-W i" says:

> CTRL-W i     split window and jump to declaration of identifier under the cursor.

So there we are — it does a jump to definition (same as `:tag` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>), only in a split.